# How to parse a JSON array inside an APEX web service request's body

Tags: json, plsql, oracle-apex

The body of a certain REST request has the following JSON defined:

```
{
    "employees": [{
            "employee_id": 900,
            "first_name": "a",
            "last_name": "Sato",
            "email": "a.sato",
            "hire_date": "01-06-2018",
            "job_id": "AD_PRES"
        },
        {
            "employee_id": 901,
            "first_name": "b",
            "last_name": "Sato",
            "email": "aas.sato",
            "hire_date": "01-06-2018",
            "job_id": "AD_PRES"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to refer to the request body (i.e.JSON string above) and parse the it so I can save them to my database via PL/SQL.

APEX version is 5.1.1.00.08

Comment: Do you really mean request body rather than response body?

Comment: Yes I meant the request body.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the APEX_JSON package.

```
declare
  p_json clob := '
  {
    "employees": [{
            "employee_id": 900,
            "first_name": "a",
            "last_name": "Sato",
            "email": "a.sato",
            "hire_date": "01-06-2018",
            "job_id": "AD_PRES"
        },
        {
            "employee_id": 901,
            "first_name": "b",
            "last_name": "Sato",
            "email": "aas.sato",
            "hire_date": "01-06-2018",
            "job_id": "AD_PRES"
        }
    ]
  }';

  type t_employee is record (
    employee_id number
   ,first_name varchar2(255)
   ,last_name varchar2(255)
   ,email varchar2(255)
   ,hire_date date
   ,job_id varchar2(255)
  );
  type t_employees is table of t_employee index by pls_integer;

  l_employees t_employees;
begin
  apex_json.parse(p_json);

  for i in 1 .. apex_json.get_count(p_path => 'employees') loop
    l_employees(i).employee_id := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'employees[%d].employee_id', p0 => i);
    l_employees(i).first_name  := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'employees[%d].first_name',  p0 => i);
    l_employees(i).last_name   := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'employees[%d].last_name',   p0 => i);
    l_employees(i).email       := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'employees[%d].email',       p0 => i);
    l_employees(i).job_id      := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'employees[%d].job_id',      p0 => i);
    l_employees(i).hire_date   := to_date(apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'employees[%d].hire_date', p0 => i), 'mm-dd-yyyy');
  end loop;

  -- Do what you want here with l_employees
  -- In this example I'm just outputing it.
  for i in 1 .. l_employees.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line (
      'employee_id(' || i || ') => ' || l_employees(i).employee_id || ' / ' ||
      'first_name(' || i || ') => ' || l_employees(i).first_name || ' / ' ||
      'last_name(' || i || ') => ' || l_employees(i).last_name || ' / ' ||
      'email(' || i || ') => ' || l_employees(i).email || ' / ' ||
      'job_id(' || i || ') => ' || l_employees(i).job_id || ' / ' ||
      'hire_date(' || i || ') => ' || l_employees(i).hire_date
    );
  end loop;
end;
```

If you're using 12c, you can also use [JSON_TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/function-JSON_TABLE.html) which is a way better and faster way.

Comment: In 12.2, you can solve this with SQL https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/json-support-in-oracle-database-12cr1

Comment: Thank you for the parsing advise! Tried it here and it works.

Comment: One more thing, how can I refer to the JSON array as it comes from the request body?

Here's what I have tried so far but is currently unsuccessful getting a 400 Bad Request return (with error message: Expected a value but got: START_ARRAY)

Via APEX's SQL Workshop -> Restful Services -> Parameters section, I defined a variable:

`name: employee
bind variable: employee
access method: in
source type: uri
parameter type: string`

Comment: Via APEX's SQL Workshop -> Restful Services -> Source  section, I added this code:
`
declare
  p_json clob := :employees;

  --some code
  
  type t_employees is table of t_employee index by pls_integer;

  l_employees t_employees;
begin

  apex_json.parse(p_json);

  for i in 1 .. apex_json.get_count(p_path => 'employees') loop
    --some code
  end loop;

  for i in 1 .. l_employees.count loop
    --some code
  commit;
  
  :response := 'success';
end;
`

Comment: You can use the built-in `:body` parameter, which is a blob, so you'll have to convert it to varchar2 using the `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2` function or to a clob using any other method, depending on how big you're expecting your request body.

Comment: Verified both answers. Thanks!